# Sub script out of range

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have written a code that generates csv files. I keep getting a subscript out of range error. 
Please find the code below. I would appreciate any help on this issue.

**Note :** 
Column f in main consists of the index numbers of the worksheets. 
Column e in main consists of the pathnames where each of the files will be stored.

```
Sub Gencsv()
    For i = 3 To 12
        Dim a As String
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Select
        a = Range("f" & i).Value
        b = Range("e" & i).Value
        Filename = b

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(a).Visible = True
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(a).Copy

        Filename = b
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename, FileFormat:=xlCSV
        ActiveWindow.Close
        Sheets(a).Select
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
        Sheets("Main").Select
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        Range("c2").Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is throwing the error 'Subscript out of range' is because your workbook does not have a sheet with the index the column E is specifying.

Also make sure that you do not copy the sheet("main"). I do not see a condition which skips the 'main' sheet or avoids it from being copied/moved as a CSV.

Here is the corrected version:

```
Sub Gencsv()
On Error GoTo x
For i = 3 To 12
    Dim a As Integer
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Select
    ' Get Sheet("Main") Index
    ' MsgBox "Index of Main: " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Index
    mainIndex = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Index
    ' Get Sheet Index from column F
    a = Range("f" & i).Value
    ' Get CSV Filepath from column E
    b = Range("e" & i).Value

    If a = mainIndex Then
        'Do nothing if the current index is of the Sheets("Main")
    Else
        Filename = b
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(a).Visible = True
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(a).Copy

        Filename = b
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename, FileFormat:=xlCSV
        ActiveWindow.Close savechanges:=True
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Sheets(a).Select
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
        Sheets("Main").Select
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        Range("c2").Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

Next i
x:
MsgBox "[ERROR] Sheet with index: " & a & " does not exist!"
End Sub
```